# Golang azure blob store, 0b blobs and overwrites downloaded blobs data

Tags: azure, go, azure-blob-storage

Currently using: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go

overview: I'm currently downloading a blob from the azure blob store, parsing the blob and uploading a transcribed blob back to the store in another folder called filtered.

Problem: The blob uploaded is not in the folder filtered but in the root directory and the blob is 0B with no data. The blob upload also seems to destroy the blob i just downloaded resulting in the blob being 0B with no data. Downloading the blob works fine and i'm able to get the []byte array of the data.

Code:

```
import (
"bufio"
"fmt"
"os"
"strings"
"strconv"
"math/big"
"bytes"
"io/ioutil"
"github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/storage"
"compress/gzip"
"encoding/base64"
"crypto/md5"
)

func main() {
    var filter bool = true                                                  //check smart filter
    test := 0
    configfile, err := os.Open("config.txt")                                //open configfile
    check(err)                                                              //check file opened
    ConfigScanner := bufio.NewScanner(configfile)                           //open buffer
    ConfigScanner.Scan()                                                    //get serial number
    serialnum := ConfigScanner.Text()
    configfile.Close()                                                      //close the config file
    CanLUT := ParseDBC("file.dbc")                                          //parse the associated DBC file
    check(err)                                                              //check file opened
    m := make(map[int64]string)                                             //map of last seen message
    //Azure API
    client, err := storage.NewBasicClient(accountName, accountKey)          //get client from azure
    check(err)
    bsc := client.GetBlobService()                                          //access blob service
    cnt := bsc.GetContainerReference("containerblob")                           //get container of the blob
    LBP := storage.ListBlobsParameters{}                                    
    LBP.Prefix = "dev4/dev4"                                                //only get blobs with dev4/dev4 prefix
    list, err := cnt.ListBlobs(LBP)                                         //get list of all matching blobs
    check(err)
    for _, b := range list.Blobs {                                          //read all blobs from azure with prefix dev4/dev4
        oa := make([]byte,0)
        fmt.Println("getting blob: ",b.Name)
        readCloser, err := b.Get(nil)                                       //get blob data
        check(err)
        bytesRead, err := ioutil.ReadAll(readCloser)                        //read blob data to byte[]
        check(err)
        if len(bytesRead) < 1 {
            continue
        }
        br := bytes.NewReader(bytesRead)
        zr, err := gzip.NewReader(br)                                       //use gzip reader for zipped data
        check(err)
        uz, err := ioutil.ReadAll(zr)                                       //uz byte[] of unzipped file
        check(err)
        readCloser.Close()                                                  //close the reader
        zr.Close()                                                          //close gzip reader
        r := bytes.NewReader(uz)
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
        for scanner.Scan() {                                                //loop on each line in the input file
            temp := ParseToFrame(scanner.Text())                            //parse the line into a usable struct
            _, exists := m[temp.nodeid]                                     //check if the frame has alread been seen and is stored in the hashmap
            if exists {                                                     //if exists in the map
                if ChkDuplicate(m, temp) {                                  //is the msg a duplicate? if true the message isnt so add it
                    m[temp.nodeid] = temp.data                              //update the data to the hashmap
                    DecodeFrame(temp, &oa, CanLUT, filter, serialnum)       //decode the frame and output it to another file
                }
            } else {                                                        //DNE in map so add it
                m[temp.nodeid] = temp.data
                DecodeFrame(temp, &oa, CanLUT,filter, serialnum)            //decode the frame and output it to another file
            }
        }//end blob file
        filestr := strings.Split(b.Name, "_")[1]
        filestr = "filtered/filtered_" + filestr
        var buffout bytes.Buffer
        gz := gzip.NewWriter(&buffout)
        _, err = gz.Write(oa)
        check(err)
        gz.Flush()
        gz.Close()
        compressedData := buffout.Bytes()
        //push block blob to azure
        fmt.Println("uploading: ",filestr)
        clientnew, err := storage.NewBasicClient(accountName, accountKey)           //get client from azure
        check(err)
        senderbsc := clientnew.GetBlobService()                                         //access blob service
        sendercnt := senderbsc.GetContainerReference("storeblob")                           //get container of store blob
        bblob := sendercnt.GetBlobReference("filtered_" + strings.Split(b.Name, "/")[1])
        err = bblob.CreateBlockBlob(nil)
        check(err)
        blockID := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("00000"))
        err = bblob.PutBlock(blockID, compressedData, nil)
        check(err)
        list, err := b.GetBlockList(storage.BlockListTypeUncommitted, nil)
        check(err)
        uncommittedBlocksList := make([]storage.Block, len(list.UncommittedBlocks))
        for i := range list.UncommittedBlocks {
            uncommittedBlocksList[i].ID = list.UncommittedBlocks[i].Name
            uncommittedBlocksList[i].Status = storage.BlockStatusUncommitted
        }
        err = b.PutBlockList(uncommittedBlocksList, nil)
        //check if upload was good.
        CheckHash(&compressedData,filestr,sendercnt)
        check(err)
        if(test == 0){
            break       //test only read one file
        }
        test++
    }//end for blobs     
}//end main
```

Comment: Why are you uploading individual blocks? This seems unnecessarily painful. That SDK has a `createBlockBlobFromReader()` method that takes care of all the blob operations for you. (see [the source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/master/storage/blockblob.go))

Comment: I'm not sure how createBlockBlobFromReader() is different from CreateBlockBlob(). Are you saying i should create one block and upload all my blobs to it to avoid making a new block each time? Not sure how to do this. Also the azure I'm uploading to is private so do i need to set the metadata and properties of the blob before upload?

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidMakogon said, you can use the API [`CreateBlockBlobFromReader`](http://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/storage#Blob.CreateBlockBlobFromReader) of Azure Storage SDK for Go to upload from any reader implements the interface `io.Reader` to Azure Blob Storage.

Here are my sample code as below.

```
accountName := "<your-storage-account-name>"
accountKey := "<your-storage-account-key>"
client, _ := storage.NewBasicClient(accountName, accountKey)
blobClinet := client.GetBlobService()
containerName := "mycontainer"
container := blobClinet.GetContainerReference(containerName)

// Two sample ways for uploading
// 1. Upload a text blob from string reader
blobName := "upload.txt"
blob := container.GetBlobReference(blobName)
strReader := strings.NewReader("upload text to blob from string reader")
blob.CreateBlockBlobFromReader(strReader, nil)

// 2. Upload a file from file reader
fileName := "hello.png"
file, _ := os.Open(fileName)
blobName := "hello.png"
blob := container.GetBlobReference(blobName)
blob.CreateBlockBlobFromReader(file, nil)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    compressedData := buffout.Bytes()
    //push block blob to azure
    fmt.Println("uploading: ",filestr)
    blockID := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("00001"))
    newblob := cnt.GetBlobReference(filestr)
    err = newblob.CreateBlockBlobFromReader(bytes.NewReader(compressedData),nil)
    check(err)
    err = newblob.PutBlock(blockID, compressedData, nil)
    check(err)
    list, err := newblob.GetBlockList(storage.BlockListTypeUncommitted, nil)
    check(err)
    uncommittedBlocksList := make([]storage.Block, len(list.UncommittedBlocks))
    for i := range list.UncommittedBlocks {
        uncommittedBlocksList[i].ID = list.UncommittedBlocks[i].Name
        uncommittedBlocksList[i].Status = storage.BlockStatusUncommitted
    }
    err = newblob.PutBlockList(uncommittedBlocksList, nil)
    check(err)
```

This fixed my problem looking at the original i had a typo calling.

```
list, err := b.GetBlockList(storage.BlockListTypeUncommitted, nil)
```

This caused azure to get both a new blob called filestr and to overwrite the original blob.